# how to split date and time from the datetime variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
 var d ={
            "title": "q",
            "message": "q",
            "date_time": "March 28, 2018 7:12 PM",
            "user_id": "5abb6c929d5b611b01875e9b"
        }

        var s = d.date_time.split(',')
        console.log(s)
```

Comment: Use the normal Date object: `var datetime = new Date(d.date_time);` you can split whatever you need from there. Also [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com) is very easy to use and can do a lot with dates.

Comment: Take care when spelling JavaScript. http://JavaScriptIsNotJava.io

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a library like `moment.js`, I'd suggest creating a native JavaScript `Date` object and working with that to extract whatever part you need from it.

```
const date = new Date(d.date_time);
console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`);
console.log(`${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`);
```

A couple of things to note:

- The return value of `getMonth`is zero-based
- You'll have to use your own logic to convert 24-hour to 12-hour AM/PM time if that's required
- Beware of time zones

Answer (score 0):

You can use the js plugin **moment.js**:

```
var dateStr = moment(d.date_time).format('LL');
var timeStr = moment(d.date_time).format('LT');
```

See here for info: https://momentjs.com

If you need an array then just do this:
var cars = [dateStr, timeStr];

Comment: i need a solution to split the March 28, 2018 7:12 PM as 
['March 28, 2018','7:12 PM']
can anyone help with regular expression

Comment: what do you mean with "we can't update"? you don't need to update the database. I just decalared to variables, one for the time and one for the date

Comment: if you need regex than please write your question properly

Comment: i'm new to the stackoverflow...sorry

Comment: @RajeshKumarJ I added an extension to my answer. The result will be the same:  ['March 28, 2018','7:12 PM']

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression

```
myArray = /(\w+ \d+), (\d+) (\d+):(\d+) (\w+)/g.exec('March 28, 2018 7:12 PM');
```

You will get array of

```
0:"March 28, 2018 7:12 PM"
1:"March 28"
2:"2018"
3:"7"
4:"12"
5:"PM"
```

You can work with that.

Or if you need to just split date and time use:

```
myArray = /(\w+ \d+, \d+) (\d+:\d+ \w+)/g.exec('March 28, 2018 7:12 PM');
```

Your result will be:

```
0:"March 28, 2018 7:12 PM"
1:"March 28, 2018"
2:"7:12 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d ={
    "title": "q",
    "message": "q",
    "date_time": "March 28, 2018 7:12 PM",
    "user_id": "5abb6c929d5b611b01875e9b"
};
var data = d.date_time.split(' ');
var date = data[0]+' '+data[1]+' '+data[2];
var time = data[3]+' '+data[4];
console.log(date);
console.log(time);
```

Split the string with space , then get the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d ={
    "title": "q",
    "message": "q",
    "date_time": "March 28, 2018 7:12 PM",
    "user_id": "5abb6c929d5b611b01875e9b"
},
new_date_time = new Date( d.date_time ),
s = new_date_time.toLocaleDateString(),
t = new_date_time.toLocaleTimeString();

console.log('Date: ' + s );
console.log('Time: ' + t )
```